# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' when using the pycountry library

Tags: python, pandas, pycountry-convert

I have a column in a DataFrame with country code and I want to convert it to the name to plot a graph using the library `pycountry`

```py
def get_country(n):
    country = countries.get(alpha_2 = n)
    return country.name
```

I want to implement the function above using on the DataFrame like this

```py
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(get_country)
```

and I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: If the country isn't found, `countries.get()` will return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` returns `None` by default if the key isn't found. You need to check for this.

```
def get_country(n):
    country = countries.get(alpha_2 = n)
    if country:
        return country.name
    else:
        return n # keep the original code if no name found
```